# How to set the background of button programmatically when that is at some of conditions in android?

Tags: android

I am going to change the background of button in android when text value is lower than 1.

```
btn_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int temp = convertStringToInt(text_count.getText().toString());
                if (temp != 1){
                    text_count.setText(temp-1);
                } else {
                    btn_minus.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_circle_gray_minus);
                }
            }
        });
```

btn_minus is the object of Button. and btn_minus.setBackground is not working now.

Comment: Are you using the material components Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setBackgroundResource() function instead of the setBackground().

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for changing button background color :

```
  btn_minus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_circle_gray_minus);
```